# Excel compare table to find existence in a 2D array

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I am having trouble on finding the pair match from the left table to generate the existence mapping on the right table.  I have tried lookup and wildcard matches but the first column got some duplicating data so that it will just stopped after comparing the first column of data.  is there any excel command that could continual compare the whole list for the most coverage?
thanks.

[image: Excel raw data and wanted output diagram]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Perhaps following array formula may help you:

```
{=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($H2=$A$2:$A$12)*(IFERROR(SEARCH(I$1,$B$2:$D$12),0)>0))>0,"*","")}
```

Array formula after editing is confirmed by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `enter`

[image]

Comment: thank you so much that worked so well, was not able to make use of sumproduct before.